# Automatically mirroring a GitHub repo

Tags: git, github, mirror

I suspect this question has been asked before, though all I can find are similar but distinct questions or the same one with only solutions that do not work for me.

There is a repository on GitHub that I have no control over and would like to mirror. With mirror I mean have a clone that gets updated automatically. I want this mirror to also be on GitHub. Preferably any solution would not involve much configuration or setup work from my side. However if needed I can have a script run using a cron on some VPS.

Can I create such a mirror purely via GitHub? If not, are there ready to use scripts to do this?

Comment: what do you want to achieve with the mirror? Since it'd be automatically updated, any deletes and prunes would affect your copy, too.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a local Git repo mirroring tool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interesting question, considering all [Eclipse repos](http://git.eclipse.org/c/) are mirrored [on GitHub](https://github.com/eclipse).

But, as illustrated by the [recent (April 2013) article](http://waynebeaton.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/eclipse-at-github/) from [Wayne](http://waynebeaton.wordpress.com/about/), the re is no automatic GitHub way to mirror a repo.

> As far as I know, GitHub provides no mechanism to schedule a regular pull (correct me if I’m wrong), which means that it would become our responsibility to push to the GitHub clone.

See also [bug 402183](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=402183).

So a script on a VPS (ie, something *you* setup) remains the surest way to implement this.

Building on "[HowTo mirror your git repository on Github](https://www.chiliproject.org/projects/chiliproject/wiki/HowTo_mirror_your_git_repository_on_Github)", you would need your own local clone, with a script which would:

- regularly pull from the GitHub repo
- push to the mirror on Github

Update 2015 (2 years later): a tool like [`beefsack/git-mirror`](https://github.com/beefsack/git-mirror) (in [go](http://golang.org)) is:

> designed to create and serve read-only mirrors of your Git repositories locally or wherever you choose.
>   A recent GitHub outage reinforces the fact that developers shouldn't be relying on a single remote for hosting code.